# foreach with every 10th and 2nd changes

Tags: php, html, laravel

So i am dealing with coupons that I need to print. I prepared the view and I am passing coupons to the view:

```
public function printSelected($ids){
        $couponIDs = explode(',', $ids);
        $selectedCoupons = Coupon::find($couponIDs);

        return view('admin.coupons.print')->with(compact('selectedCoupons'));
    }
```

Now I need to loop through them in a certain manner.

1. every 10 coupons I need a new "page" block because 10 coupons fit into a page block
2. every second coupon I need a new table row because 2 coupons or table data fits into one row

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this but I find it very readable to use the `chunk` method of the `Collection` object. Another option would be to use modulus (`$index % 10 === 0`).

```php
<div class="coupons">
    {{-- Create chunks of 10 as this is the max per page --}}
    @foreach($selectedCoupons->chunk(10) as $pageCoupons)
    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">
            <table>
                {{-- Create chunks of 2 so every row is filled with up to 2 coupons --}}
                @foreach($pageCoupons->chunk(2) as $rowCoupons)
                <tr>
                    {{-- Loop over the row coupons to create the columns --}}
                    @foreach($rowCoupons as $coupon)
                    <td>
                        <span class="coupon">{{ $coupon->code }}</span><br>
                        <hr>
                        <span class="name">{{ $coupon->user->name }}</span>
                    </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection's [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-chunk) method to loop over chunks of your coupons:

```html
<div class="coupons">
    @foreach ($selectedCoupons->chunk(10) as $page)
    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">
            <table>
                @foreach ($page->chunk(2) as $row)
                <tr>
                    @foreach ($row as $coupon)
                    <td>
                        <span class="coupon">{{ $coupon->code }}</span><br>
                        <hr>
                        <span class="name">{{ $coupon->user->name }}</span>
                    </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```